# How do I integrate the indefinite integral, $\frac {\sin t}{t+1}$ w.r.t to t.

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I integrate the indefinite integral, $\frac {\sin t}{t+1}$ w.r.t to t.

$$\int \frac{\sin t}{t+1} \,dt$$

I've tried by parts, but seems impossible. I can't think of a good subsitution too.

Help appreciated!!

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4497/how-to-show-the-integral-symbol-on-this-site/) is some tutorial about writing integrals and we also have [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for writing mathematics in general.

Comment: Pretty sure that isn't going to be an elementary function.

Comment: Thanks martin XD I was on a iphone so i was going to find it hard to google how to write integrals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is an elementary integral, but we can use special functions.

Use the substitution $s=t+1$ giving
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{\sin(t)}{t+1}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\int\frac{\sin(s-1)}{s}\,\mathrm{d}s\\
&=\int\frac{\sin(s)\cos(1)-\cos(s)\sin(1)}{s}\,\mathrm{d}s\\
&=\cos(1)\mathrm{Si}(s)-\sin(1)\mathrm{Ci}(s)+C\\[6pt]
&=\cos(1)\mathrm{Si}(t+1)-\sin(1)\mathrm{Ci}(t+1)+C
\end{align}
$$
Where $\mathrm{Si}(x)$ is the [Sine Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) and $\mathrm{Ci}(x)$ is the [Cosine Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html).

Comment: This is the only way, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (an electrician's point of view):

Consider the parameter-dependent integral:

$$I(a)=\int \frac{\sin at}{t+1} \,dt$$  The Laplace transform of $I(a)$:

$$\mathcal{L}\,I(a)=\frac{\ln(t^2+s^2)}{2(1+s^2)}-\frac{\ln(t+1)}{1+s^2}+\frac{s\arctan{\frac{t}{s}}}{1+s^2}=F(s) $$  The inverse Laplace transform:

$$\mathcal{L^{-1}}F(s)=I(a)=-(\sin a) \ln(t+1)+\int_{0}^{a}\frac{\sin[(t+1)x-a]}{x}dx+\text{C}$$ I would say that the result is even a closed form solution.

Comment: How is the result any more 'closed-form' than the starting point was?

Comment: Haven't learnt laplace yet, but thanks anyway!!! Seems like its impossible to integrate with beginning calculus.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki It does not include an indefinite integral.

Comment: @MartinGales But it includes an arbitrary constant of integration!  I might as well say '$\int \frac{\sin t}{t+1} dt = \int_0^t\frac{\sin x}{x+1} dx+C$'.  It's true, and it expresses the integral in terms of a definite integral, but it's useless for evaluating the initial integral and I wouldn't call it any more closed-form.